# SQL statement much slower from ODBC than in T-SQL

Tags: c++, sql, sql-server, performance, odbc

I have a C/C++ DLL that is connecting to SQL and issuing a large number of ODBC queries rapidly in a loop. The only thing is that it is turning out to be so much slower from the ODBC DLL than running the query from T-SQL in Management Studio. Many orders of magnitude slower.

At first I thought it might be the query itself, but then I stripped it down to a simple "select NULL" and still got the same results.

I was wondering if this is expected or whether there is some ODBC setting that I am missing or getting wrong?

First I connect like this (for brevity I have omitted all error checking, however, retcode is returning SQL_SUCCESS in all cases):

```
char *connString = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=.\\ENT2012;uid=myuser;pwd=mypwd";
...
retcode = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &henv);
retcode = SQLSetEnvAttr(henv, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (void*)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0);
retcode = SQLSetEnvAttr(henv, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (SQLPOINTER)SQL_OV_ODBC3, SQL_IS_UINTEGER);
retcode = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, henv, &hdbc);
SQLSetConnectAttr(hdbc, SQL_LOGIN_TIMEOUT, (void*)5, 0);
retcode = SQLDriverConnect(
    hdbc, 
    0,
    (SQLTCHAR*) connString,
    SQL_NTS, 
    connStringOut,
    MAX_PATH, 
    (SQLSMALLINT*)&connLen, 
    SQL_DRIVER_COMPLETE);
```

Then I prepare the statement, bind a parameter (unused in this example), and bind a column like this:

```
char queryString = "select NULL;";
SQLLEN g_int32 = 4;
SQLLEN bytesRead = 0;
...
retcode = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hdbc, &hstmt)
retcode = SQLPrepare(hstmt, queryString, SQL_NTS);
retcode = SQLBindParameter(hstmt, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, 
    SQL_C_LONG, SQL_INTEGER, sizeof(int), 0, spid, 0, (SQLLEN*)&g_int32))
retcode = SQLBindCol(hstmt, 1, SQL_C_CHAR, col_1, 32, &bytesRead);
```

Finally, I repeatedly call the query (e.g., 10000 times) in a loop like this:

```
retcode = SQLExecute(hstmt);
retcode = SQLFetch(hstmt);
SQLCloseCursor(hstmt);
```

This takes about 90 seconds to run 10000 times in the ODBC DLL. Testing on a 4 core Windows 2008 R2 Server running SQL 2012 x64.

On the other hand, if I run, what looks to me to be, an equivalent test in Management Studio, it takes less than a second:

```
declare @sql varchar(128), @repeat int;
set @repeat = 10000;
set @sql = 'select NULL;';
while @repeat > 0 begin
    exec(@sql);
    set @repeat = @repeat - 1;
end;
```

Can someone point out something that I am overlooking? Some flaw in my logic?

Thanks.

Neil Weicher

[www.netlib.com](http://www.netlib.com)

Comment: Does your loop include the connect, or just the execute?

Comment: To put it in context, you are measuring about 9 milliseconds of overhead for the C++ DLL that is using ODBC -- several additional layers of code.  This doesn't *necessarily* seem unreasonable, although I would expect something a bit smaller. This question may be more appropriate for dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @RemusRusanu - the loop just includes the execute. the connect and prepare are done once at the beginning.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - would you suggest I delete the question and move it there?

Comment: btw - could the choice of Driver={SQL Server} have anything to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

*This is too long for a comment*

```
declare @sql varchar(128), @repeat int;
set @repeat = 10000;
set @sql = 'select NULL;';
while @repeat > 0 begin
    exec(@sql);
    set @repeat = @repeat - 1;
end;
```

does not realistically simulate the same as 10000 remote calls. `exec` bypasses a *lot* of the internals of setting up a request. To simulate 10000 calls do this in SSMS:

```
select NULL;
go 10000
```

and measure. Output as text probably should be used to avoid timing around SSMS grid display.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not all that familiar with the T-SQL stuff but here are a couple things to consider.

Your ODBC driver has to transfer data via your network and I suspect the T-SQL execution does not.  Next to disk IO, transfering data on the network is one of the slowest things your ODBC driver will have to do.  You may find that the driver is spending considerable time either waiting on the data to travel to clearing data off the wire.

Also, it's not clear to me that your T-SQL example actually moves and data but your ODBC example does when SQLFetch is called.  The T-SQL may just be executing the query and never fetching any data.  So, removing SQLFetch from the loop might be a more equal comparison.

To see if data transfer is your limiting factor estimate how much data will be included in all the records you fetch with ODBC and try to move that much data between the two machines with something like FTP.  An ODBC driver will never be able to fetch data faster than a simple raw transfer of data.  I see you are just fetching NULL so not much in your result set but the driver and database still transfer data between them to service this request.  Could be several hundred bytes per execution\fetch.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Both tests are being done on the local machine. Do you see anything in the ODBC setup that might make a difference? For example, might the choice of Driver= make a difference?

Comment: Typically, ODBC drivers still communicate via TCP even when they are on the same machine as the database.  I've seen some exceptions to this with Oracle's own ODBC driver (for Oracle).  SQL Server also allows connections via named pipes.  I have messed with that much but I think local named pipes might provide and advantage your scenario.

Comment: As far as the Driver= section of your connection string, that specifies which ODBC driver you are using.  I am guessing yours uses Microsoft's driver but "Driver=DataDirect 7.1 SQL Server Wire Protocol" would specify the DataDirect driver, assuming it is installed of course.  That could have an impact as not all drivers are created equal; some perform better than others.  You can read about ours here: http://ow.ly/ACHDu

Comment: Keep in mind my earlier comment about fetching the data.  I don't see anything consuming the data in yoru T-SQL example.  SQLFetch will tell the driver to pull the data off the wire and copy it to an application.  That will take more time that executing a query and ignoring the results.

Comment: Thanks I will give it a try. Do I use connection strings in the same way as before?

Comment: With the exception of maybe needing to set an option to specify using named pipes yeah, the rest should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. I solved it by changing the "Cursor Default Mode" setting of the DSN for the ODBC driver (through the ODBC Administrator tool) from "READ_ONLY" to "READ_ONLY_STREAMING". This alone increased the speed of my application (query data and write them to file) from 260 seconds to 51 seconds using Java 32-bit and from 1234 seconds to 11 seconds using C++. 
See this post: http://www.etl-tools.com/forum/visual-importer/1587-question-about-data-transformation-memory-usage?start=6